# Sorting by a column with data from an associated table In Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am coming from VisualBasic 6 and learning Rails.

I have a table of invoices which relates directly to my receivable_invoices table in the database. It currently includes these columns amongst others:

```
description
client_id
value
```

`client_id` is a foreign key to a table that contains columns including

```
client_id
name
```

The user can currently sort the table I am showing based upon these tables except for the client `name` column which looks to the clients table rather than the `receivable_invoices` table. When the user clicks on the Client column it sorts by `client_id` rather than the client name.

I would like it to sort by client name.

Here is the relevant code which I have plundered from Ryan Bates' "[Sortable Table Columns](http://railscasts.com/episodes/228-sortable-table-columns)".

Here's where I call the sortable method:

```
<th><%= sortable "client_id", "Client Name" %></th>
```

And here is the sortable method itself:

```
def sortable(column, title = nil)

    title ||= column.titleize
    css_class = column == sort_column ? "current #{sort_direction}" : nil
    direction = column == sort_column && sort_direction == "asc" ? "desc" : "asc"

    link_to title, {:sort => column, :direction => direction}, {:class => css_class}
end
```

What do I need to pass the sortable method to sort on client name rather than client_id?